# How to find the number of 1's in a binary representation of a number?

Tags: javascript, binary

From other searches, I found that this problem is called 'Hamming Weight' or 'Population Count'. There are lot of answers out there given with so many statistics?
I need to find the solution in a simple way? Complexity is not a big deal. 
Is there any in-built function in JavaScript like Java's Integer.bitCount?

I'm currently doing this as follows.

```
var binary = 3;
var original = binary;
var count = 0;
while(binary>0)
{
    binary = binary >> 1 << 1;
    if(original-binary==1)
        count++;
    original = binary >> 1;
    binary = original;
}
```

Is there a better, more simple as well as elegant way for this?

Comment: If it's truly a string, `str.split('1').length`, but that's not javascript at all is it, it's Java

Comment: related to code review(http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: @adeneo sorry wrong details. I need to perform this on a number.

Comment: Then it's `numb.toString().split('1').length`, tada !

Comment: Does the above methods have high time complexity? Which should I prefer?

Comment: Prefer over what, the code you've posted is not javascript, and you're asking for javascript, it's sorta hard to understand what you really want ?

Comment: @adeneo You are right. That wasn't JavaScript. What I'm wondering is that if the answer is this simple, why does everyone else suggest some complex methods to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
var binary = 10;
var result = binary.toString(2); //Converts to binary
var count = result.split(1);//  count -1 is your answer
alert((result.split('1').length-1));
```

can also be written as

```
(binary.toString(2).split('1').length-1)

toString(2)  : helps to split it in a base2 format which is binary, can do this in a range of 2- 36 (iam not sure about the range)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to count 1 digit in binary representation we can use regular expression like this.

> number.toString(2).match(/1/g).length

Answer (score 2):

A simple way without using built-in functions:

```
function f(n){
    let i = 0;
    do if(n&1) ++i; while(n>>=1)
    return i;
}

// example:
console.log(f(7)); // 3
```

Comment: This seems to fail for large numbers (for example, `8224580541325813` should produce `28`, but this function produced `17`). This is because the right-shift operation will operate assuming your number is only a 32 bit number, and truncate anything beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

```
  function numOfOnes(n) {
    if(n === 0) return n;
    return (n & 1) + numOfOnes(n >>= 1);
  }
```

Basically this approach belongs to recursive call.
It has the base condition when no number to evaluate.
 Otherwise it calls itself on `(n >>= 1)` and add last digit `(n & 1)` to result.
eg. **7** has binary representation **111** = 1+1+1 = **3**
**17** has binary representation **10001** = 1+0+0+0+1 = **2**

Comment: Good answer, but an explanation of how and why it works would make this a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function countOnesInDecimal(num) {
  let count = 0;
  let binary = num.toString(2);
  const splitted = binary.split('');
  for (const iterator of splitted) {
    if (iterator === `1`) {
      count += 1;
    }
  }

  return count;
}
console.log(countOnesInDecimal(3));
```

Comment: there is no need to split the string, you can just as easily iterate over a string instead of an array